# Monoid in the category of endofunctors and Monoid as a category with one object

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories, monads

Quoting from [Categories for the Working Mathematician by Saunders Mac Lane](http://books.google.com/books?id=MXboNPdTv7QC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22monoid+in+the+category+of+endofunctors%22+mac+lane&source=bl&ots=feQWTkH2Uw&sig=tv-1JwaMOygKGmFE2vM2FhJVS9o&hl=en&ei=5iWsTJCkBIPSsAPQwJ36Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> All told, a monad in X is just a monoid in the category of
>   endofunctors of X, with product × replaced by composition of
>   endofunctors and unit set by the identity endofunctor.

At the same time a Monoid is a category with one object. Given a Monoid in the category of endofunctors of X as above, how do we get a category with one object from there? Please specify exactly what the object and the morphisms of this category are.

Followup question: [Elements of the Monoid in the category of endofunctors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988800/elements-of-the-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quote you mention does not say that monads are monoids in the usual sense; it says that they are [monoids in the monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category) of endofunctors of $X$. A monoid in a monoidal category (or monoid object, as suggested by Derek Elkins in a comment) is *not* a monoid; that's a [red herring](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle). In general, a monoid object is an oject of a category which is not necessarily concrete, so it need not be any kind of set; in particular, it does not need to have any kind of elements. But seeing a (usual) monoid as a one-object category means precisely that you identify its elements with the arrows of a category; so you can't do that for monoid objects.

You can however, identify such monoids with one-object [enriched categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category#InMonoidCat), exactly in the same way that classical monoids can be identified with classical one-object categories (in fact the classical case is just enrichment over sets with the cartesian product).

Comment: I tend to use the term "monoid object" to mean a model of the theory of monoids in a category potentially different from $\mathbf{Set}$.