# Elements of the Monoid in the category of endofunctors

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories, monads

Quoting from [Categories for the Working Mathematician by Saunders Mac Lane](http://books.google.com/books?id=MXboNPdTv7QC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22monoid+in+the+category+of+endofunctors%22+mac+lane&source=bl&ots=feQWTkH2Uw&sig=tv-1JwaMOygKGmFE2vM2FhJVS9o&hl=en&ei=5iWsTJCkBIPSsAPQwJ36Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> All told, a monad in X is just a monoid in the category of
> endofunctors of X, with product × replaced by composition of
> endofunctors and unit set by the identity endofunctor.

So we have the category $X$ with Endofunctor $T: X \rightarrow X $

And two natural transformations:
$$\eta: 1_X \rightarrow T $$
$$ \mu: T^2 \rightarrow T $$

Question: Since $T$ is the object of this Monoid, what are its elements? I understand that the elements are:

$$ \forall x \in X: T(x), T^2(x), T^3(x),...,T^n(x),...$$

Is that correct?

This is a followup to [Monoid in the category of endofunctors and Monoid as a category with one object](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988411/monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-and-monoid-as-a-category-with-one-object)

Comment: As I said in my answer to your first question : this monoid does **not** have elements.

Comment: If you skip ahead to chapter VII, you'll see the discussion of the kind of monoid Mac Lane is talking about. This monoid in the category of endofunctors is *not* "a set with a binary operation, etc", but one discussed in the sense of this chapter. Many categories have no sensible notion of "element", and functor categories are among such categories.